# ar: libcrypto.so: file format not recognized when installing openssl-1.1.1g

Tags: openssl, installation, shared-libraries

I'm getting this error when I run `make install` after compiling `openssl-1.1.1g`.

```
link /my/dir/lib/libcrypto.so -> /my/dir/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
install libcrypto.so -> /my/dir/lib/libcrypto.so
install libcrypto.so.1.1 -> /my/dir/lib/libcrypto.so
ar: /my/dir/lib/libcrypto.so: file format not recognized
ar: /my/dir/lib/libcrypto.so.new: file format not recognized
make: *** [Makefile:370: install_dev] Error 1
```

The commands I'm using are:

```
tar xvf openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1g
./Configure --prefix=/my/dir shared linux-x86_64
make
make install
```

There don't seem to be any errors from configuration or `make`.

I've also tried `./config --prefix=/my/dir shared` instead of `./Configure` with the same result.

I'm on a RedHat-based Scientific Linux.

I found a similar discussion [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6641), but it didn't give me insight into fixing the problem.

I'm trying to install it in my personal location because I'm not an administrator of the machine in question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the machine had an old version of perl, which openssl config scripts use to create the Makefile. v5.10.1 appear to be not enough. I installed v5.30.2 and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the thread you reference has the correct answer: upgrade `Text::Template` to at least 1.46 (using a `cpan` variant). [One comment](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/6641#issuecomment-403568805) says this is required because `append_text_to_output` is used in the build scripts. Presumably upgrading Perl itself solved your problem because it brought a new version of the module.